# Unity2D: Repeat explosion animation within a random short time fixed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble getting my explosion animation to work for my player to use on my enemies. Basically want I want is that when the player presses a button, use yield waitfortime and then the explosion animation is plays, simple right? However here's the catch! I want the explosion animation to only play one at a time; so when one explosion animation is finished the next explosion animation will play but at a random short amount of time, for example explosion 1 plays, 3 seconds later explosion 2 plays, 6 seconds later explosion 3 plays and so on (remember random value on longer than 10 second.) I also want the explosions to only happen depending on how ever many spawned prefabs (enemies) are in camera view. To clarify, I have already created my explosion animation via using the animator and that I have tried many of my own methods, like onBecamevisible and OnTriggerEnter2D, etc. but had some troubles with it working, so I came to this website for some support. Oh and I am also using C# Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used unity much but something like this should get you on the right path...

```
Random rand = new Random();
int minTime = 1; //must wait this many seconds
int maxTime = 6; //max seconds to wait

if (this.animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("YourAnimationName")) {
   int waitTime = rand.Next(minTime, maxTime);
   yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
   animation.Play("animation2");
}
```

Again, this in untested but should help a little.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out!

Comment: Hey thank you, it worked! I get a few errors now an then though I did fixed them. Thank you SOOOOO much! :)